# error: exportArchive: No "teamID" specified and no team ID found in the archive

Tags: react-native, github-actions, devops

An error occurs when building the IOS-BUILD of react-native application in github actions
The android apk build is successfully done, but facing this issue while IOS build process. Here's the error:
[image]

So my question is there any way I can get the TEAM ID or i can create the ipa file without team ID?